# Adding tags to a sentence on each line

Tags: sed

So, basically I have lines like this:

```
TEXT1910\text0001 “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ”
```

And I want them look like this:

```
TEXT1910\text0001 <s> “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” </s>
```

I tried to use this to make it work by using this command:

```
cat text.ign | sed -e 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/ <s> \1 <\/s>\2/' | less
```

But this produces:

```
<s> TEXT1910\text0001 “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” </s>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your goal correctly, try:

```
sed 's| | <s> |; s|$|</s>|'
```

For example, starting with your file:

```
$ cat text.ign 
TEXT1910\text0001 “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ”
```

And, running our command:

```
$ sed 's| | <s> |; s|$|</s>|' text.ign
TEXT1910\text0001 <s> “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” </s>
```

How it works:

- `s| | <s> |` replaces the first blank with `<s>`.

  Sed allows any character to be used as the delimiter in the substitute command.  Here we are using `|` instead of the traditional `/`.
- `s|$|</s>|` adds `</s>` to the end of the line.

  Since we are using `|` as the delimiter, there is no need to escape the backslash in `</s>`.

#### What happened with the original command

From the question, we have:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/ <s> \1 <\/s>\2/' text.ign 
 <s> TEXT1910\text0001 “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” </s>
```

The issue here is that sed regexes match the *leftmost longest* match.  That means that the first `\(.*\)` matches everything from the beginning of the line to the last space in the line.  The other `\(.*\)` matches anything after that last space.

Since the line in the example ends in a space, this means that  `\(.*\)` matches the entire line and  the other `\(.*\)` matches nothing.  Thus `<s>` is placed before the entire line and `</s>` is placed after it.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple just use:

```
sed -Ee 's/(.*[0-9])(.*)/\1 <s>\2 <\/s>/'
```

In your case :

```
cat file | sed -Ee 's/(.*[0-9])(.*)/\1 <s>\2 <\/s>/' | less
```

But you should prefer using filename after sed command, try to avoid pipe, i.e.:

```
sed -Ee 's/(.*[0-9])(.*)/\1 <s> \2 <\/s>/' file
```

For editing file directly using option `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ $1 = $1 " <s>"; $(NF+1) = "</s>"; print }' file
TEXT1910\text0001 <s> “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” </s>
```

This simply adds a space and the opening `<s>` tag after by the first whitespace-delimited field, and then the closing `</s>` tag as a new field at the end. It then prints the modified line.

Note that this will collapse multiple spaces in the data into a single space.

Answer (score 0):

What you are requiring is that the first double quote to the last be enrobed in an html like construct, which is doable like this:

```
sed -e 's|".*"|<s> & </s>|'  inputfile
```